# How to send list of model objects in json format to API in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am working on a Food Delivery App in **Flutter** and I have a list of model objects in my cart System. I need to send this list to API in JSON format so I convert that to JSON before sending it to server but i am getting error:

errors: {: [Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Metronic.Models.FoodOrderInsert' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

I am beginner in Flutter and your kind response will highly be appreciated.
I am currently converting list and sending it to API like this:
I have my List of modelbjects:

```
List<FoodDetail> foodOrderDetails = [...]
var jsonObjectsList = [];
//Here I convert my list of FoodDetails into list of jsonObjects
for (var item in foodOrderDetail) {
  jsonObjectsList.add(item.toJson());
}
await http
    .post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: ApiURLs.header,

  body: jsonEncode(jsonObjectsList)
)
```

And my API required data is:

```
[{
"OrderId": 0,
"ProductId": 0,
"Quantity": 0,
"Price": 0}]
```

my FoodDetail class contain same these properties and converted to json but the problem I think is in conveting whole list to json.

Comment: Can you also put you json data to pass to your api?

Comment: @ArbiterChil I just updated my question, can you please have a look again.

Answer (score 2):

i suggestion to use DIO lib its automatically convert your data to json
check it: https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Answer (score 1):

use this class to parse the server response
FoodExample foodExample=FoodExample.fromJson(jsonEncode(jsonObjectsList))
with this line you will have access to all the attributes of the class

```
class FoodExample {
  int orderId;
  int productId;
  int quantity;
  int price;

  FoodExample({this.orderId, this.productId, this.quantity, this.price});

  FoodExample.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if(json["OrderId"] is int)
      this.orderId = json["OrderId"];
    if(json["ProductId"] is int)
      this.productId = json["ProductId"];
    if(json["Quantity"] is int)
      this.quantity = json["Quantity"];
    if(json["Price"] is int)
      this.price = json["Price"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["OrderId"] = this.orderId;
    data["ProductId"] = this.productId;
    data["Quantity"] = this.quantity;
    data["Price"] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using this technique and converting my objects to json. actually i am sending data to server no getting data from server. but the error I thing invoked when I send my jsonObjects list to server.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question by using Dio package,
That was the error due to http package internal code.
My Method for posting list to Server:

```
Future<int> insertFoodOrderDetails(List<FoodOrderDetail> foodOrderDetail) async {
var dio = Dio();
var mapData;
var url = ApiURLs.baseUrl + ApiURLs.insertFoodOrderDetails;
var jsonObjectsList = [];
for (var item in foodOrderDetail) {
  jsonObjectsList.add(item.toMap());
}
await 
    dio.post(
  url,
  queryParameters: ApiURLs.header,
  data: jsonObjectsList
)
    .then((value) {
   mapData = value.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
});
if (mapData['Status'] == 'Inserted Successfully') {
  print(mapData['Id']);
    return mapData['Id'] ;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
```

}